# How to check SQS Filter Policy if subscribed to SNS of different account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an SQS which is subscribed to the SNS of a different account. I wanted to check the filter policy of the subscription but I don't have access to the SNS account. Is there a way by which I can check the SNS subscription filter policy in my SQS account?

Comment: No, you cannot. Although there is way to add filter in your sqs account

Comment: How can I add filter in sqs account ?